# Check date is weekend or a holiday, double check

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop

Ok sorry about the wording on this one but it's doing my head in, I need to find the earliest delivery date,

```
$useStartDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
```

I have 2 functions

The first checks to see if a date is a weekend or a Monday and increments it accordingly

```
function checkWeekend ($CheckDateDate){
    if (date("w", $CheckDateDate) ==  1) { //monday
        return strtotime('+1 day', $CheckDateDate);
    }
    else if (date("w", $CheckDateDate) ==  0) { //sunday
        return strtotime('+2 day', $CheckDateDate);
    }
    else if (date("w", $CheckDateDate) ==  6) { //saturday
        return strtotime('+3 day', $CheckDateDate);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The second check to see if the date is in my database of holidays

```
function checkHoliday ($CheckDateDate) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblNonDeliveryDates Where NonDeliveryDate = '$CheckDateDate'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        return strtotime('+1 day', $CheckDateDate);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is check both functions until they both return 0, Where I'm having trouble going back and checking the date is not a weekend after it's been incremented because it's a Holidays. This is what I have, but I know that it's wrong.

```
$CheckDate = $useStartDate;
while ($Checkdate > 0)
{
    $LastChecked = $CheckDate;
    $Checkdate = checkWeekend($CheckDate);
    $Checkdate = checkHoliday($CheckDate);
}
echo $LastChecked;
```

Hope that's clear.

Comment: `return = 0;`? Is that a typo in your actual code?

Comment: You're running your check functions on "$Checkdate" (lowercase d), but you're defining '$CheckDate' with a capital D at the top of your while loop.  Are these just typos, as well as the 'return = 0'?

Comment: yeah sorry Passerby @aztechy these are typos, I simplified the code a bit and missed these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$CheckDate = $useStartDate;
while ($Checkdate > 0)
{
    $weekend = false;
    $holiday = false;

    if( checkWeekend($Checkdate) != 0)
        $weekend = true;
    else if( checkHoliday($Checkdate) != 0)
        $holiday = true;
    else
        $Checkdate = 0;

    if( $weekend )
       $Checkdate = checkWeekend($Checkdate);
    else if( $holiday )
       $Checkdate = checkHoliday($Checkdate); 

     $LastChecked = $Checkdate;
}
echo $LastChecked;
```

Comment: This just puts me in an endless loop? I changed $Checkdate = $useStartDate; also.

Comment: Try it now. Sorry missed the condition.. should work fine now.

Comment: Brilliant! I moved the $LastChecked to the start of the loop because $CheckDate has to be 0 to break the while loop, So I set it before it's changed. Thanks so much for your time!